# Problem connecting yarn packages in docker-cmpose

Tags: reactjs, ruby-on-rails, docker, docker-compose, esbuild

When I start the server locally using the bin/dev command, everything works just fine and esbuild compiles all files without errors

## #bin/dev

```
if gem list --no-installed --exact --silent foreman; then
  echo "Installing foreman..."
  gem install foreman
fi

# Default to port 3000 if not specified
export PORT="${PORT:-3000}"

exec foreman start -f Procfile.dev "$@"
```

But when I run my containers using docker-compose up I get an error:

```
app-1       | 10:54:38 web.1  | started with pid 9
app-1       | 10:54:38 js.1   | started with pid 10
app-1       | 10:54:38 js.1   | yarn run v1.22.17
app-1       | 10:54:38 js.1   | $ esbuild app/javascript/*.* --bundle --sourcemap --format=esm --outdir=app/assets/builds --public-path=/assets --loader:.js=jsx --watch=forever
app-1       | 10:54:39 js.1   | ✘ [ERROR] Could not resolve "@hotwired/stimulus"
app-1       | 10:54:39 js.1   | 
app-1       | 10:54:39 js.1   |     app/javascript/controllers/application.js:1:28:
app-1       | 10:54:39 js.1   |       1 │ import { Application } from "@hotwired/stimulus"
app-1       | 10:54:39 js.1   |         ╵                             ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
app-1       | 10:54:39 js.1   | 
app-1       | 10:54:39 js.1   |   You can mark the path "@hotwired/stimulus" as external to exclude it from the bundle, which will remove this error and leave the unresolved path in the bundle.
app-1       | 10:54:39 js.1   | 
app-1       | 10:54:39 js.1   | ✘ [ERROR] Could not resolve "@hotwired/stimulus"
app-1       | 10:54:39 js.1   | 
app-1       | 10:54:39 js.1   |     app/javascript/controllers/hello_controller.js:1:27:
app-1       | 10:54:39 js.1   |       1 │ import { Controller } from "@hotwired/stimulus"
app-1       | 10:54:39 js.1   |         ╵                            ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
app-1       | 10:54:39 js.1   | 
app-1       | 10:54:39 js.1   |   You can mark the path "@hotwired/stimulus" as external to exclude it from the bundle, which will remove this error and leave the unresolved path in the bundle.
app-1       | 10:54:39 js.1   | 
app-1       | 10:54:39 js.1   | ✘ [ERROR] Could not resolve "@hotwired/stimulus"
app-1       | 10:54:39 js.1   | 
app-1       | 10:54:39 js.1   |     app/javascript/controllers/react_controller.js:1:27:
app-1       | 10:54:39 js.1   |       1 │ import { Controller } from "@hotwired/stimulus"
app-1       | 10:54:39 js.1   |         ╵                            ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
app-1       | 10:54:39 js.1   | 
app-1       | 10:54:39 js.1   |   You can mark the path "@hotwired/stimulus" as external to exclude it from the bundle, which will remove this error and leave the unresolved path in the bundle.
app-1       | 10:54:39 js.1   | 
app-1       | 10:54:39 js.1   | ✘ [ERROR] Could not resolve "react"
app-1       | 10:54:39 js.1   | 
app-1       | 10:54:39 js.1   |     app/javascript/controllers/react_controller.js:2:18:
app-1       | 10:54:39 js.1   |       2 │ import React from "react";
app-1       | 10:54:39 js.1   |         ╵                   ~~~~~~~
app-1       | 10:54:39 js.1   | 
app-1       | 10:54:39 js.1   |   You can mark the path "react" as external to exclude it from the bundle, which will remove this error and leave the unresolved path in the bundle.
app-1       | 10:54:39 js.1   | 
app-1       | 10:54:39 js.1   | ✘ [ERROR] Could not resolve "react-dom/client"
app-1       | 10:54:39 js.1   | 
app-1       | 10:54:39 js.1   |     app/javascript/controllers/react_controller.js:3:27:
app-1       | 10:54:39 js.1   |       3 │ import { createRoot } from 'react-dom/client';
app-1       | 10:54:39 js.1   |         ╵                            ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
app-1       | 10:54:39 js.1   | 
app-1       | 10:54:39 js.1   |   You can mark the path "react-dom/client" as external to exclude it from the bundle, which will remove this error and leave the unresolved path in the bundle.
app-1       | 10:54:39 js.1   | 
app-1       | 10:54:39 js.1   | ✘ [ERROR] Could not resolve "react"
app-1       | 10:54:39 js.1   | 
app-1       | 10:54:39 js.1   |     app/javascript/components/App.jsx:1:18:
app-1       | 10:54:39 js.1   |       1 │ import React from "react";
app-1       | 10:54:39 js.1   |         ╵                   ~~~~~~~
app-1       | 10:54:39 js.1   | 
app-1       | 10:54:39 js.1   |   You can mark the path "react" as external to exclude it from the bundle, which will remove this error and leave the unresolved path in the bundle.
app-1       | 10:54:39 js.1   | 
app-1       | 10:54:39 js.1   | 6 errors
app-1       | 10:54:39 js.1   | [watch] build finished, watching for changes...
```

Case is correct in all files

Here are additional files that may help solve the problem:

## DockerFile:

```
# /path/to/app/Dockerfile
FROM ruby:2.7.5-alpine

ENV BUNDLER_VERSION=2.1.4

RUN apk add --update --no-cache \
      binutils-gold \
      build-base \
      curl \
      file \
      g++ \
      gcc \
      git \
      less \
      libstdc++ \
      libffi-dev \
      libc-dev \
      linux-headers \
      libxml2-dev \
      libxslt-dev \
      libgcrypt-dev \
      make \
      netcat-openbsd \
      nodejs \
      openssl \
      pkgconfig \
      postgresql-dev \
      tzdata \
      yarn

RUN gem install bundler -v $BUNDLER_VERSION

ENV BUNDLE_PATH /bundle
ENV BUNDLE_BIN /bundle/bin
ENV GEM_HOME /bundle
ENV PATH $GEM_HOME/bin:$BUNDLE_BIN:$PATH

WORKDIR /app

COPY Gemfile Gemfile.lock ./

RUN bundle config build.nokogiri --use-system-libraries

RUN apk update && bundle check || bundle install

COPY package.json yarn.lock ./

RUN yarn install --check-files

RUN yarn global add esbuild

COPY . ./

ENTRYPOINT ["./entrypoints/docker-entrypoint.sh"]
```

## #File /entrypoints/docker-entrypoint.sh

```
#!/bin/sh

set -e

if [ -f tmp/pids/server.pid ]; then
  rm tmp/pids/server.pid
fi

bundle exec bin/dev
```

## #File docker-compose.yml

version: '2.24.1'

services:
app:
build:
context: .
dockerfile: Dockerfile
depends_on:
- database
ports:
- "3000:3000"
volumes:
- .:/app
- gem_cache:/usr/local/bundle/gems
- node_modules:/app/node_modules
env_file: .env
environment:
RAILS_ENV: development
database:
image: postgres:12.1
volumes:
- db_data:/var/lib/postgresql/data
- ./init.sql:/docker-entrypoint-initdb.d/init.sql

volumes:
gem_cache:
db_data:
node_modules:

## #File package.json

```
{
  "license": "MIT",
  "dependencies": {
    "@hotwired/stimulus": "3.2.2",
    "esbuild": "0.19.11",
    "react": "18.2.0",
    "react-dom": "18.2.0"
  },
  "scripts": {
    "build": "esbuild app/javascript/*.* --bundle --sourcemap --format=esm --outdir=app/assets/builds --public-path=/assets --loader:.js=jsx"
  }
}
```

I tried adding this to package.json

```
"esbuild": {
    "external": [
      "@hotwired/stimulus",
      "react",
      "react-dom/client"
    ]
  }
```

I tried to add all 3 packages globally, as I did with esbuild, but it didn’t help either.

I tried updating bundler, that didn't help either.

I tried specifying specific package versions in package.json, that didn’t help either.

Comment: It looks like you have a Compose `volumes:` block that overwrites various parts of your image with a combination of host content and named volumes.  This could cause the problems you're seeing; does deleting that entire block help?

Comment: (Also consider splitting your Node and Ruby components into separate containers, and letting Docker manage their individual lifecycles instead of using a process runner like Foreman.)

Comment: I removed node-modules from volumes, everything compiled successfully, but now for some reason the site at localhost:3000 does not open

Comment: As a result, I moved the js into a separate container and everything works fine